# COM method call returns Catastrophic Failure

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, com

**Note:**

- Pass **BSTR** variable to **COM** method, **HRESULT** return is `8000FFFF`
- Previous calls with **interface pointer**, was **successful**: HRESULT is `0`
- Execution, inside Visual Studio **succeeds**, outside **fails** - release and debug

**Illustration:**

```
const char *simFile;
simFile = new char;
//omitted
_bstr_t simFileToOpen(simFile);
BSTR raw_sim_Open = simFileToOpen.copy();
SysFreeString(simFileToOpen);
delete simFile;

hresult = pis8->raw_Open (raw_sim_Open); //0x8000FFFF returned
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simFile looks to be a single character stored inside a const char*.

It is not a NULL terminated string, unless it is an empty string and it's contents are 0.
Are you sure you didn't mean to do something like:

```
const char *simFile = new char[1024];
strcpy(simFile, "path");
```

Even better yet you can just use SysAllocString to get a BSTR directly.

```
BSTR str = SysAllocString(_T("path"));
```